# Android giving me a lot of errors after updating some SDK tools

Tags: java, android

Recently, I realised that after updating some SDK tools from the standalone SDK manager, I encountered a lot of (weird) problems with Android Studio, such as not being able to see `ProgressBar` in the Android preview pane to the right. It gives me the error

```
Exception raised during rendering: Binary XML file line #-1: Error inflating class <unknown> (Details)
```

However, it runs on my phone just fine, so I ignored it. Lately, when I tried to run my app using ADB, the app crashed with some errors in the logcat. They are as follows:

```
08-07 20:57:44.745 31113-31113/com.example.android.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: com.example.android.app, PID: 31113
                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.app/com.example.android.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3149)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5146)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:197)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:343)
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                at com.example.android.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:70)
                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:5146) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:197) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1687) 
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199) 
08-07 20:58:24.565 2840-2840/com.example.android.app E/VdcInflateDelegate: Exception while inflating <vector>
                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 1
                                                                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.twGetColorStateList(TypedArray.java:438)
                                                                  at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColorStateList(TypedArray.java:420)
                                                                  at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateStateFromTypedArray(VectorDrawableCompat.java:518)
                                                                  at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.inflate(VectorDrawableCompat.java:472)
                                                                  at android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.createFromXmlInner(VectorDrawableCompat.java:436)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager$VdcInflateDelegate.createFromXmlInner(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:708)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:348)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:181)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:689)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:186)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:77)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:83)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:28)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:41)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:193)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:173)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:511)
                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:71)
                                                                  at com.example.android.app.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:27)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
08-07 20:58:24.595 2840-2840/com.example.android.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                          Process: com.example.android.app, PID: 2840
                                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.app/com.example.android.app.SplashActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3149)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
                                                           Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:343)
                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:312)
                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:277)
                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                              at com.example.android.app.SplashActivity.onCreate(SplashActivity.java:28)
                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6550)
                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1120)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3102)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3248) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:197) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1681) 
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145) 
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872) 
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404) 
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

I remember very clearly that I did not change any of my app's theme. Part of my `SplashActivity.java` is as follows:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // line 27
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash); // line 28
    }

    // ...
}
```

And my `MainActivity.java`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // line 70

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

The following image shows what SDK I have installed:

[image: List of installed SDK]

Does anyone have any idea on why this might have happened? Feel free to ask anything in the comments below. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried Build -> Clean Project ?

Comment: @ClarkWilson Yup, but it didn't work (it took this long to clean and run my app) :(

Comment: Maybe one of your views was deprecated? Try deleting your imports, and reimporting the AppCompat versions of all your classes in SlashActivity and MainActivity.

Comment: @ClarkWilson Nope it didn't work, thought I managed to solve it (partially). See my answer. Would be useful to know why this downgrading works though.

Answer (score 0):

I partially solved my problem by downgrading my `buildToolsVersion` in gradle from `23.0.3` to `23.0.2`. This solved all of my problems except for the `ProgressBar` problem. I'll post an update when I manage to solve this.